# ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, rake, actionmailer

I have a problem with using ActionMailer (rails 3.0.19) in rake tasks. Whenever I want to send email using rake task I get error:

**rake aborted!
You can no longer call ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options directly. You need to set config.action_mailer.default_url_options. If you are using ActionMailer standalone, you need to include the routing url_helpers directly.**

I have config.action_mailer.default_url_options set in environments/*.rb and do not use ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options call in my app.

Using rake task mailing doesn't work, but using console works fine.

Moreover, when mail view contains link_to, it crashes. But without link_to, it is ok.

Help needed, I have absolutely no idea what to do.
Thanks.

Comment: I have found a solution! I had line:   
**include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers # Allows access to Rails routes**
before tasks. If I move this line into task, the error disappears.